# Why are rollover/console port cables not twisted?

Tags: networking

ever since I learned about console cables I felt there was something off about them, and only once I got one for a Cisco ASA did I notice what it was, it's a completely flat cable, end to end!

I'm really curious as to why that is, and i haven't been able to find anything online about it, mostly the difference between them and straight through cables.

Comment: It is my understanding that twisting reduces noise both internal and external, and thus allows much longer cables. https://www.mercurywire.com/twisting-and-cabling/

Answer (score 0):

They're not twisted because they are [RS-232 serial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Data_and_control_signals) cables, not Ethernet cables.

Serial ports usually do not have separate Rx/Tx pairs, unlike Ethernet – they have only a single ground wire for *all* signals. (Console cables run at *very* low rates compared to Ethernet, so this usually works well enough.)